# How to hide banner text from nav menu?

Tags: html, css

Hello i have a banner text that is showing everytime, even when i press the nav menu mobile it doesn't hides.

[image]

[image]

I tried setting position relative on banner text div but it is still showing my text...

My CSS

```css
.banner {
  background-image: url(../images/banner1.webp);
  /*imagen de fondo banner*/
  background-size: cover;
  /*la imagen se expande a la pantalla*/
  min-height: 100vh;
  /*altura del 100 del viewport del dispositivo*/
  background-color: rgb(30, 30, 30);
  /*color de fondo*/
  background-blend-mode: soft-light;
  /*propiedad de color*/
  animation: banner 25s infinite linear;
  /*animación que llama a banner, 25seg, infinito */
}

.banner .banner-text {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height: 80px;
  font-size: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

As i said before i tried adding position relative / z-index to banner-text but it keep showing it above the mobile menu

```css
@media (max-width: 1024px){
    .banner .banner-text{
        font-size: 36px;
        position: relative;
     }
}
```

This is my whole css https://pastebin.com/zMgZ9S2Y

Comment: Can you provide your markup for a [mcve]?  It will make this much easier to understand.

Comment: I have added the css. The banner-text should NOT be showing if i am navigating in my mobile menu. It should be BEHIND the menu and not ABOVE :/

Comment: Thanks for including more context; however, adding more CSS is less helpful here than adding the HTML to which the CSS should be applied.  A [mcve] is what you should strive for-- enough code to recreate and understand the issue without any additional code superfluous to the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting a lower z-index value in the mobile view.

```
@media (max-width: 1024px){
  .banner .banner-text{
  font-size: 36px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
 }
}
```

And this z-index value should be less than the nav menu elements.

Comment: Hey bro, adding that hides it completely. Check: https://ibb.co/zhbfxJM and https://ibb.co/LSPP03d . It gets hidden even when i close the nav menu.

Comment: I haven't used z-index bro... i don't have it in my code, should i add one in order to work your example above?

Comment: yes, set higher z-index value to the nav elements so it will display on top. And you can remove the z-index: -1;

Comment: I tried adding a z-index 10 to my .header .nav and/or .header .nav .nav-menu and removing the z-index -1 from .banner .banner-text but it keeps showing above my mobile menu :/ This is my short CSS https://pastebin.com/zMgZ9S2Y

Comment: Set 
@media (max-width: 1024px){
.header .nav .nav-menu{
z-index:1;
}
}

This is the media query which is going to be loading in your mobile view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236923/discussion-between-dula-and-diego-donoso).

Comment: after trying everything i just found the solution.... i had to set banner-text position to relative (it was in absolute), and give to .header a z-index... i don't know why it worked... everyone told me to give a z-index to the nav or nav menu but the solution was to give it to the header class lol.... thanks everyone !